# What is wrong with the range of j?

Tags: python, math

This is my first code in python and i completely can't get why the code in 5-th string must contain `math.sqrt(i))+1` instead of just `math.sqrt(i)`, because otherwise squares of prime numbers are added to the result.
How to solve this is the easiest and most natural way? Thanks you all in advance

```
import math
n=int(input("Print n: "))
prime_list=list(range(2,n))
for i in range(2,n):
    for j in range (2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(i))+1):
        if i % j == 0:
            try:
                prime_list.remove(i)
            except:
                j+=1
        continue

print(prime_list)
```

Comment: Except for the problem of rounding error, and the fact that floor+1 is more appropriate than ceil+1, this *is* the "easiest and most natural way" to iterate over the right range. (It's not the easiest and most natural way to achieve the overall goal of constructing a list of primes, though. `prime_list.remove(i)` is slow, you should really be breaking the loop instead of using a blanket try-except, the `j+=1` in the except block gets stomped in the next iteration anyway, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You need `j` to run all the way through the sqrt of `i`.  Remember that a Python range does *not* include the terminal value.

For instance, `range(2, 7)` does not include `7`.  To find that 49 is *not* a prime, you need `range(2, 7+1)`, so that `j` will take on the value `7`.

Comment: Thank you, i'm steel newbee and confused in basic things :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's Python.

In Python, the syntax `range(x, y)` generates a sequence of

```
x, x+1, x+2, ..., y-2, y-1
```

So if you want a value to be included in the range, the second parameter must be greater than the value (not equal), and that's why you should use `math.floor(...) + 1` and cannot omit the `+1` part. Otherwise when i is the squate of a prime, j will not iterate over that prime, thus causing the error you're facing.

Comment: Important note, i'll remember